Turning list of key value into canonical python quickly
I have an application that can only work with the following type of data (Cassandra and some custom SDK):
{'key': 'key Name', 'value': 123}

I typically want this as:
{'key Name': 123}

Is there a rapid and smart way to convert between these two formats in python. I can do it, but want to do as effectively as possible and use the most efficient as possible. Is there a name for the first type of format?

{d['key']: d['value']}

Thanks, that not the issue, its more of a complex list of them. I can do w list comp, but is there anything "built-in" that goes between these two?

check out dict comprehension

@disruptive, no, there is not a default dictionary format.  If you hare a list of them: [{d['key']: d['value']} for d in list_of_dicts]

@disruptive Why don't you want to use dict-comprehension? It is built-in logic.

Please edit the question to clarify what you really want.
